# how to split words in a file with all characters that are not letters in java

Tags: java, string, split

I have this text file and I need to split all words and count them. In the file I have all of the following characters ("." , "," , "!" , "?" , " " , ";" , ":" , "-"). 
How do I use the split() method to make sure non of those characters will be counted?

Comment: `text.split("\\W+")` ?

Comment: Start by sanitizing the text (removing all these characters) and then split.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto that might be a problem, for example, the word "can't" might get split to "can" and "t" - which is not desired.

Comment: "can't" means "can not", which is 2 words... (I know, it is most common to spell it "cannot", and some even think these two have different meanings, just wanted to show, how unspecific the question is...)

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot. Thankfully I don't have any words in the file that include apostrophe so it is all good :)

Answer (score 0):

Youcan use this:

```
String[] parts = originalString.split("\\W+")
```

Or if you want to be more specific:

```
String[] parts = originalString.split("[.\\,\\!\\?\\  \\;\\:\\-\"]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Small Java 8 example where you get a map of all the distinct Words and their length.

```
final Function<String, Stream<String>> split = txt -> Stream.of(txt.split("[ ,!.?:;-]"));

final String txt = "a, ab c! def?";

final Map<String, Integer> words = Stream.of(txt)
                                         .flatMap(split)
                                         .filter(s -> s.length() > 0)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(String::new, String::length, (a, b) -> a));
```

Yields

```
{ab=2, a=1, c=1, def=3}
```

I don't know if this is exactly what you want. If you just want a simple list of all the Words, then use `Collectors.toList()`